# How to detect if Java (JRE) is used on machine?

Tags: java

We have some vulnerability alerts on our VM due to an outdated JRE package.
I'm trying to understand whether we're using it in the first place.

In the **Task Manager** I only see these two processes associated with java:
[image]

There is no java.exe or javaw.exe, does that mean there is no application that depends on the package and we can remove it?

Comment: It just means that there's no other Java application running.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/989652/finding-all-programs-which-are-using-java-on-windows-server-2012

Comment: if you think the task manager shows all installed applications you have far more serious problems than a supposed vulnerability in a specific JVM version.

Comment: Thank you @shmosel
But because this VM doesn't contain a lot of applications I just went through them and checked if they required Java.

Comment: @jwenting My expectation is that task manager at least shows all apps that are running right now.

Comment: @Amir it would, apparently no Java processes were running at the time :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just delete it OR remove from autorun in Task Manager and if programs will ask for a newer version - download or enable in TM.
You see that processes uses 0% of your CPU - it's nothing. Java software installed on PC and always keep a few process in autorun. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dM5ZZ.png)